# Four different birds of the same family

Tags: riddle

- *They are a group of four different birds belonging to the same family.*
- *The other birds of their family and all the birds of other families have agreed on what to chirp when they flock together while those four are still undecided.*

***Who are those four birds?***

---

*Hint*

> *Flocking together is an act of solidarity.*

Comment: Sounds like French politicians! I could give you some names but I think it is unlikely to be the answer you're waiting for :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the four birds are

> Spain, San Marino, Kosovo and Bosnia and Herzegovina

Because

> These are the only four countries whose national anthems don't have any words. In essence, they don't have anything to *chirp* as an act of solidarity.

The families in this case are probably

> Continents, with all four birds above belonging to Europe.

Comment: This totally has to be it - nice one. I was focussing too much on languages in my thinking about this, but this interpretation of 'chirping' is surely the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Could the four birds be...

> Countries: Iran, Libya, Eritrea and Yemen?

They are a group of four different birds belonging to the same family.

> The four birds are countries from the world.

The other birds of their family and all the birds of other families have agreed on what to chirp when they flock together while those four are still undecided.

> As the other birds (countries) signed the **Paris Agreement** as the international treaty for climate change, these four countries did not fully agree with it yet.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thinking required to answer this question. However, in your answer, you have used a very general term for family. There is a family in which the four birds belong along with other birds of the same family. There are also birds from OTHER families. Also, the chirping part is not addressed. But your thinking is very near to the final answer!